# Linked-lists in c

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I'm fairly new to coding in c and have stumbled upon a problem. The code below is what I have so far.

The trouble I'm running into is the syntax, more specifically on how to loop through the list. I've spent the past week looking at different resources but none explained how to work with a similar struct data type. The way I've attempted to loop through the list results in an error, and I'm having trouble adding the job in the right place since the list is in increasing order - based on the reference number.

The other problem I've run into is within function 5. I'm not entirely too sure of how to return both an integer and character value through a char pointer, unless you return just the entire job_node. As of now, I have casted the value of the node to be a char.

Since I haven't coded much in c - any other suggestions on how to make the code more efficient without changing the values of the functions would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Why don't you want to return a pointer to a (optionally `const`) `job_node`? For me it looks like the right solution. Your caller will need both members, the identifier and the name. It can ignore the linking pointer.

Comment: `create_job_node` does not return a value.  Surely you get a compiler warning about that.

Comment: You can pass NULL to free, so `if (lst != NULL){ free(lst); }` can be re-written as simply `free(lst)`.  There's no need for the redundant check.

Comment: _Side note:_ Please do _not_ put spaces around the arrow operator (`->`). Please change all (e.g.) `foo -> bar` to `foo->bar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linked list is a container of nodes, and each node has some data payload. Often each data record has a key, a value used to compare two records. In students' assignments in general the data is a simple letter or a number. In your case is a pointer to a "job post".

**Below I will show you an alternative way to write his**. But first...

It is important to note that the list is a container of nodes, not a list of job posts. A list is not a node, a node is not a list, and the data is not a node.

Mixing these things like you did in your program leads only to problems: you will not be able to use the list to *contain*  other data, for example. You will have trouble changing the implementation of the list without changing the data. You will need to change the list functions if you change a field in the job post. Only problems.

#### example

```
bool job_insert(int refNum, char job_name[], struct job_list * list);
```

should be like

```
    int     insert_l( Job* job_post ,List* the_list ,int(*compare_function)(void*,void*));
```

**Why?**

- Using the former way you can use just a pointer to `Job` --- in general you should use a `void*` so you can use anything inside the data record without the need to change the arguments list.
- this way if you add a field to `Job` or change perhaps the reference number to a `char[]` to add a check-digit you do not need to change a thing here
- `compare_function()` compare two `Job` and return -1 if the 1st is greater, 1 if the 2nd is greater, or 0. This way you can change the sorting criteria at any time, just writing a new 10-line function, and have records inserted by new criteria. C `qsort()` uses this, C++ `sort()` uses this, Borland Turbo Pascal used this in the 80;s. It is simple and flexible.
- the function can be as simples as

```
int compare_reference(void* a, void* b)
{
    int first =  ((Job*) a)->reference_number;
    int second = ((Job*) b)->reference_number;
    if (first < second ) return 1;
    if (first > second ) return -1;
    return 0;
};
```

and used like this

```
    int    res = insert_l( one_job, new_jobs, compare_reference );
```

and if `res` is `0` `one_job` was inserted in `new_jobs` list at the correct position. It is also easier to read: *insert record into list according to criteria*.

And if at any time you need to use descending order or sort by another criteria you just need to pass a new function. This means that you can use the same List-related functions to contain any data. This is the reason to use only void pointers to the data element also...

#### Back to the program

This could be a test file to drive your tests:

```
    1    engineer
    2    magician
    3    astronaut
    4    actress
    5    truck driver
    6    writer
```

#### The structures

```
typedef struct
{
  int       reference_number;
  char*     job_name;

}   Job;

typedef struct node_
{
    Job*            info; // pointer to data record
    struct node_    *next;
    struct node_    *prev;

}   Node;

typedef struct 
{
    unsigned  size; // actual size
    unsigned  capacity; // limit in # of nodes
    Node*     head;
    Node*     tail;

}   List;
```

And you have a `List` that is a collection of `Node`. Each `Node` has a pointer `info` that point to a `Job`, that is the data record. Inside a `Job` you have the reference number and the job's name. `reference_number` is called `key` because it is the field used to compare `Job` records.

The `List` has no reference to `Job`, only to `Node`. `Node` has no data, just a pointer. So to use `List` to contain songs or cars or books like the next assignment in line is easy ;)

#### the functions

```
List*       create_l(unsigned); // return new List
List*       delete_l(List*); // erase one
int         insert_l( Job*,List*,int(*)(void*,void*)); // insert based on function
List*       merge_l(List*,List*,int(*)(void*,void*) ); // merge 2 lists into a 3rd
int         remove_by_ref_l(int,List*); // delete a record
char*       search_job_l(int,List*); // search for job description for a reference#
```

I believe that now you see some added convenience:

- `insert()` receives just a pointer to a `Job` and to a `List`, and the name of a function to compare 2.
- `create()` returns a pointer to a new `List` with the limit set to a max # of nodes
- `remove()` gets a reference number and if it is found in `List` removes the record and returns 0
- `search()` works the same way

I suggest you write this way. If you need help I can provide more code. I had no time today to write a full example.

Comment: That's what we call an Answer... very nice... well explained... upvote